# How to create a soft body simulation like this...?

Tags: animation, physics, collision, soft-body

I'm making the switch from Cinema 4D to Blender and I've got some problems with the soft-body simulation. I want to create an image like this:

[image]

How do I achieve this look? Let's say I have a cube and inside the cube I want to scale some spheres, that will collide with each other.

I made a test, but when I add keyframes for scaling a sphere with a soft body component, it does not work anymore.

Comment: I hope I understood well enough what you want to do: Does this maybe solve your problem: [Scaling a Soft Body object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82952/scaling-a-soft-body-object) ? See the accepted answer there ..

Comment: Blender does not support simulating pressure inside volumes yet.