# Animate location of soft body objects while simulation is running?

Tags: animation, soft-body

I have a bunch of soft body objects inside a sphere.

[image]

I want to rotate the soft body objects around the pivot point or center of the sphere they are inside of

(imagine something like a washing machine moving clothes around, the clothes get stuck from the centrifugal force, I want to do something similar with these soft bodies, but also fill the sphere).

I want something like that but without the gravity.

However, when I try to render one of the soft body objects moving to the right as a test, it basically ignored the keyframe.

[image]

How can I do the 2 simultaneously?

My settings for the soft body are like this answer here: [Scaling a Soft Body object (Inflated balloons in a box)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82952/scaling-a-soft-body-object-inflated-balloons-in-a-box?rq=1)  with "goal" unchecked.

I also want to do this while scaling the soft bodies inside, but when I tried driving the scale of one of the soft bodies by an empty, it also wouldn't change size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloth sim, Sphere as collider and Vortex force field > Shape > Point, Strenght > 8 ... ?

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Apologies for the late acceptance. While this worked it presented other problems such as making my (intentionally inflated) soft body or cloth sim objects that are spinning almost get sucked into a very different location (other than the center of the vortex) and look very strange. Nevertheless it's the closest approximation I could come to so oh well.