# Inflating a box inside a room

Tags: physics

I am trying to create air volumes of apartment rooms and thinking of using a method of inflating simple meshes like boxes similar to the following question [Scaling a Soft Body object (Inflated balloons in a box)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82952/scaling-a-soft-body-object-inflated-balloons-in-a-box) and wonder if this would be a viable method? If that is the case, how would you set up such a case? The goal is to be able to export this inflated geometry to an external simulation tool to perform building energy simulations using Energyplus, Honeybee and similar.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "create air volumes"? What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to create closed meshes consisting of planar faces that approximates rooms. from a point cloud, ifc or 3D CAD. My idea is to add a simple geometries like boxes and inflate them until the faces hits a wall/floor/roof and then merge the inflated geometries into apartments. This would allow small openings like windows and doors without messing up the model.

Comment: I'd suggst you add that explanation into your question so that others here with more experience of inflating meshes than I have can understand.

Comment: What is your overall goal?  Is it to render atmosphere such as a smoke filled room?   Don't answer below -- add to your question above so it's not overlooked.

Comment: Agreed, please edit your final goal.. what you want these volumes _for_ .. into your question

Comment: The goal is to be able to export this inflated geometry to an external simulation tool to perform building energy simulations using Energyplus, Honeybee and similar.